# entity framework with where orderby and group to get unique values

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

I have a table like below

```
Id  UserId  GroupId
-----------------------
1     4        1
2     4        2
3     5        1
4     5        2
5     6        1
```

I would like to get UserId not belongs to GroupId with query and bind with dropdown list

```
var list = _uou.UserInGroups.GetAll().where(u=>u.GroupId!=2).ToList().Select(s => new TextValuePair
                           {
                               Text = s.User.UserName,
                               Value = s.UserId.ToString()
                           })
                       .ToArray();
```

it returns results

```
Id  UserId  GroupId
-----------------------
1     4        1
3     5        1
5     6        1
```

but i want it return only result as below because if a user assign multiple group then don't show again

```
Id  UserId  GroupId
-----------------------
1     6        1
```

what should the query for above result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are aiming at?

```
var list = _uou.UserInGroups.GetAll().where(u=>u.GroupId!=2 && u.UserId == 4).ToList().Select(s => new TextValuePair
                           {
                               Text = s.User.UserName,
                               Value = s.UserId.ToString()
                           })
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hey sorry i don't want this I updated last output bit, I don't want to show user who have multiple group assigned. Only those user who have single group like UserId 6 has single groupId 1. Hope this make sense